# Truncated Fat File Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

Although I am familiar to developing in Objective-C, I still consider myself a bit of a n00b when it comes to error interpretation. I working on an application for work that others are also working on. I believe we may have different versions of Xcode, and one developer has a PC (the others and I have a MacBook). I am using Xcode 4.5.1.

**The Problem**

I am getting the following *Apple Mach-O Linker Error*:

> ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 68 to 2783300 is past end of file
>   with length 135 for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The full error is as follows (paths renamed):

> Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
>       cd /Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk -filelist /Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lsqlite3.0 -v -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Social -framework CoreBluetooth -framework MediaPlayer -framework
>   QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework FacebookSDK -o
>   /Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
>
> Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM
>   3.1svn) Target: i386-apple-darwin11.4.2 Thread model: posix  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld"
>   -demangle -dynamic -arch i386 -ios_simulator_version_min 5.1.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk
>   -o /Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   -lcrt1.o -L/Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList
>   -objc_abi_version 2 -lsqlite3.0 -no_implicit_dylibs -framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport
>   -weak_framework Social -framework CoreBluetooth -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework FacebookSDK -force_load /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a
>   -framework Foundation -lobjc -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a
>   -F/Users/me/Documents/MyApp/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/me/MyApp/trunk ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 68 to 2783300 is past end of file with length 135 for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I have found close to no documentation on this error. What's the problem? How do I resolve an error like this?

Answer (score 2):

I read this answer somewhere,

Symbolic links to files and folders (in your case some framework) are turned into fat files when they are moved from  MAC-OS/X to Windows. So whenever we copy-paste/checkout project frameworks from your MAC to windows or vice versa it gets changed, the files are modified in terms of symlinks.

So what you can do is just checkout your project files and replace the framework alone (please note the framework you are going to replace should be downloaded fresh or copied somewhere from a MAC , NOT WINDOWS).

Hope this helps someone!