# ld: truncated fat file

Tags: ios, compiler-errors

I have found these error while trying to run an XCODE application that uses NinevehGL framework:

```
ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 1478656 to 2279616 is past end of file with length 2270604 file './NinevehGL.framework/NinevehGL' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't really know whats the problem and how to solve an error like these I didn't find any documentation handling these kind of problem .

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861683/truncated-fat-file-linker-error) question/answer?

Comment: yes I did but the answer didn't really help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to made following changes in your project:-

- Include all necessary frameworks in the link phase
- Remove `-all_load` from Other Linker Flags.
- Clean the build folder and re-compiled from scratch.

[This could](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14492?focusedCommentId=260973&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-260973) very well be a permission issue, a corrupt iOS SDK install, or a corrupt Xcode install. I would remove `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulatorXXX.sdk`, then go into Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and reinstall the iOS SDK. Then try again to clean and build your project.
If you still have problems, I would consider reinstalling Xcode again.

Also have a look [how to fix](http://blog.giderosmobile.com/post/68378513314/problems-with-xcode-paths-fix) xcode path problems.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error on one of my project:

```
ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 1067056 to 2127456 is past end of file with length 770048 file '/Users/jenkins-slave-pepper/workspace/iosbuild/App/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/FirebaseInstanceID' for architecture armv7
```

The solution was to clear the pod cache and re-download everything.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf `pwd`/Pods/
pod update
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error:

```
ld: truncated fat file. Slice from *** to *** is past end of file with length *** file '***' for architecture armv7
```

The solution for me was to discard changes in one of my submodules.

EDIT:

Today it occurred again. This happened after, I needed to force restart my computer. Probably xCode or SourceTree changes submodules.

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking out the libraries from your own **git** repository?  If so, check **.gitattributes** as you may need to add ***.a** (and/or others) to the list of binary files.

In our project, we were maintaining an "archive" of the originals in a Wiki until we realized that git was "corrupting" our binary files.

snippet of the file ...

```
#
## These files are binary and should be left untouched
#

# (binary is a macro for -text -diff)
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
*.mov binary
*.mp4 binary
*.mp3 binary
*.flv binary
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:
ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 1802240 to 2416332 is past end of file with length 1067176 file '...' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What I did to solve this is re-download the frameworks from my FTP. Maybe your files are incomplete when downloading. And I found some tools for FTP might get different size files.